# why the 'size on disk' in my androidstudio is about 8 times bigger than others?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just installed the android-studio and also two emulators.
in the tutorial that I follow, 'the size on disk' in AVD is 1GB. but mine is 8GB
[image]

and this is the first one's details:
[image]

why is that? I've seen my friend's also, theirs were 1GB too

Comment: probably because of your `Internal Storage` size

Comment: It expands the more you use it. Frankly, built-in solution of emulators is pretty bad, you either use Genymotion or real device